# Dictionary(of String, String) Item property missing in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, dictionary

I am converting this VB.NET code to C#.

```
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

If dict.TryGetValue(key, val) Then
   dict.Item(key) = val & "~" & row.Item(y).ToString
Else
   dict.Add(key, row.Item(y).ToString)
End If
```

Here is the C# code. Notice the line after the If dict.TryGetValue.  Intellisense does not show a Item property in C#.  What is the correct syntax for C# ?

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out val)) {
    dict.Item[key] = val + "~" + row.ItemArray[y].ToString();
} else {
    dict.Add(key, row.ItemArray[y].ToString());
}
```

Comment: `dict[key]` -- no property

Comment: `Item[key]` is incorrect. `[]` in dictionaries are indexers and the correct way to use them is `dict[key]`.

Comment: The VB.NET syntax is *also* wrong, or at least, totally unexpected. The correct way to call an indexer property is `dict(key)`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: There are 2 ways to call an indexer in VB - one of the ways is not 'wrong'.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If the compiler expects it and you don't, one of you needs to update his expectations.

Answer (score 3):

The way you access the value of a key in a dictionary in C# is the following:

```
dict[key]
```

That being said this line:

```
dict.Item[key] = val + "~" + row.ItemArray[y].ToString();
```

*should change* like below:

```
dict[key] = val + "~" + row.ItemArray[y].ToString();
```

Comment: Christos - thank you for your answer - it is working great !

Comment: @MisterT You are welcome ! I am glad that I helped :)

Answer (score 3):

`dict.Item[key]` should be `dict[key]`. You are accessing an [Indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) and these are accessed directly from the instance on which they are defined.

See also [Indexers (c#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx)